# How to add a target to a Network Load Balancer in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I've got some CloudFormation for a Network Load Balancer.

```
  PrivateNetworkLoadBalancerSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Access to the internal network load balancer
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
  PrivateNetworkLoadBalancerIngressFromECS:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      Description: Only accept traffic from a container in the container host security group
      GroupId: !Ref 'PrivateNetworkLoadBalancerSG'
      IpProtocol: -1
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'EcsHostSecurityGroup'
  PrivateNetworkLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: network
      Scheme: internal
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetOne
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetTwo
  DummyTargetGroupPrivateNetwork:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'drop-3']]
      Port: 6379
      Protocol: TCP
      # UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

And some for setting up a Redis docker container in ECS.

```
  RedisService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !ImportValue "privatevpc:ClusterName"
      DesiredCount: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref RedisTaskDefinition

  RedisTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: redis
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: redis
          Essential: true
          Image: "redis:latest"
          Memory: 512
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 6379
              HostPort: 6379
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref CloudWatchLogsGroup
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region

  RedisTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !ImportValue "privatevpc:VPCId"
      Port: 6379
      Protocol: TCP
      HealthCheckProtocol: TCP

  RedisLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref RedisTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !ImportValue "privatevpc:PrivateNetworkLoadBalancer"
      Port: 6379
      Protocol: TCP
```

But I'm manually having to add the EC2 instance that my RedisService is deployed to as a target for the RedisTargetGroup through the AWS web console. Any idea how I can have CloudFormation do that for me?

Comment: I think you can be guided by some examples where they create several Cloudformation resources like the ones you need: [link1](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation) [link2](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/ECS) [link3](https://templates.cloudonaut.io/en/stable/ecs/)

Comment: That's where I started.

Comment: You need to add autoscaling. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the `LoadBalancers` property to `RedisService`. ECS should add the right EC2 instances to the specified target group automatically.

For example:

```
  RedisService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !ImportValue "privatevpc:ClusterName"
      DesiredCount: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref RedisTaskDefinition
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: redis
          ContainerPort: 6379
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref RedisTargetGroup
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-loadbalancers.html